# What is my test controller? Visual Studio 2010 agent

Tags: visual-studio-2010

On my Windows 2008 R2 server, I have TFS 2010 installed.

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 test controller and test agent. When configuring test agent, I don't know what to enter for the controller name, as I want to register the agent I just installed with the controller I just installed.

Any ideas what the controller's default name and port is? Or how I can find out what it is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Controller Name from the TFS if you have installed it.

Go to Test Manager -> Lab Management -> Controllers

The default Port Number is 6901

Comment: I believe this is a better solution to the original question as it doesn't rely on the loopback address.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1:6901

This did the trick. But feel free to add any comments you may have.